# UDP Client not listening

Tags: c#, udp, broadcastreceiver

I have a simple UDP Client pointing to `127.0.0.1:15000` and I have a Provider who sends me information through UDP and he says, he broadcasts the signals through the network and that he does not know what clients are listening and that I should be able to receive the signals if I point to the correct port. I know this sounds a little confusing, but what is wrong here? Is my provider wrong or I am not listening correctly to the broadcast?

```
    private int port;
    private UdpClient udp;
    public UdpReceiver(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        udp = new UdpClient(port);
        StartListening();
    }
    private void StartListening()
    {
        this.udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }
    private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (udp != null)
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            byte[] bytes = udp != null ? udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip) : null;
            if (bytes != null)
            {
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                MessageBox.Show(message);
                StartListening();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not compile because port in "new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port)" is unknown; can you please correct?

Comment: Did you verify e.g. using Wireshark that the messages really arrive at your computer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

First of all, use `new AsyncCallback(Receive)` instead of `Receive` as `BeginReceive` param.

Second, by default socket is created with broadcast send/receive being disabled. Turn it on with `udp.EnableBroadcast = true;` before `StartListening` in constructor.

Third, `Receive` method would run at thread pool thread, and you can't easily call `MessageBox.Show` there. Substitute it with `Console.Write` for testing and get informed about the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread).